# Can only click edges of svg image?

Tags: css, svg

Essentially the problem I am having is that I have three icons for social media all three are an Scalable Vector Graphic however when linked to there respective websites, I can only click the edges of the SVG Image, in other words I am unable to click the image itself just the outside of it.

Low Quality Youtube Video of the issue below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlcT0N0If0k

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```css
  .icons{

    left:692px;
    top:64px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position:fixed;
    opacity: 0.3;
    letter-spacing: 38px;
    display:block;

  }

  .u--svg-inside {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;

 &:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
   }

   object {
  width: 100%; // Optional
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">

<a href="https://twitter.com/AndrewMcCaughey" target="_blank" class="u--svg-inside">
<object data="img/twitter.svg" style=";height:25px;" type="image/svg+xml"> <img src="twitter.png" /> </object>
</a>

<a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/andrew-mccaughey-160815b8" target="_blank" class="u--svg-inside">
<object data="img/linkedin.svg" style=";height:25px;" type="image/svg+xml"> <img src="linkedin.png" /> </object>
</a>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVV5Bb6eflSDhLboZK-UVjw" target="_blank" class="u--svg-inside">
<object data="img/youtube.svg" style=";height:25px;" type="image/svg+xml"> <img src="youtube.png" /> </object>
</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Please also make a working snippet, so we can try it out

Comment: Added a snippet though without the actual svg files it doesn't seem to have the same issue.

Comment: What if you remove `:after`, seems to do nothing

Comment: I can remove the entire svg inside section and nothing changes.

Comment: And if you click, does the link work?

Comment: The links do work but as you can see in the above video i added only on the outside of the images.

Comment: Based on your video, it looks like the `<a>` element isn't wrapping around the icons. You have some `position: fixed` and `position: absolute`s in there. Give your `a` tag the CSS rule `display: inline-block` and give it a width / height.

Comment: So link work but cursor doesn't change?

Comment: Thanks, I added the display: inline-block amd width/height it doesn't seem to have solved the issue. I don't know if it might help but I will attach the files themselves below aswell.

Comment: Please update your code with the images as well, so we can see and try to understand what's going on

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/4ck0tf

Comment: The Files themselves are downloadable above, I'm not sure how to add images to the snippet above.

Comment: If it's any help im using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the `object` within the **a** element is "overriding" the pointer/click events.

To fix this, just add this CSS rule:

```
a object{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Why can only click on the edge of the SVG image?

You're actually clicking on the **a** element not the SVG, the **a** is a little bit bigger, thats why you can click it only on its edge.

[image: illustration]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurs with SVG's inside elements with an onclick handler. In this case the same fix above works:

```
svg {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```